# How to terminate DONE pin on TPL5110 when unused?

Tags: timer, one-shot

I'm using a TI [TPL5110](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tpl5110) in one-shot mode and do not need the DONE signal to shut down the timer.

I would leave it alone, but static often makes it trigger, turning the timer off. Since the TPL5110 detects a rising edge, I tried grounding or pulling it up to VDD, but with no luck, which confuses me further. It won't turn off or turn on automatically grounded or pulled up.

I don't know how to keep it from triggering, a capacitor perhaps?

Comment: Can you monitor the line on a scope?

Comment: I no longer have access to a scope, no

Answer (score 1):

A valid DONE input is a signal rising from low to high. Tie the DONE pin to ground via 10k resistor.

You also have to make sure the MCU pins are never configured to drive high if at all there is a connection from MCU output to the DONE pin.

- The DONE pulse width has to be a minimum of 100ns still. To be considered as valid input (from the datasheet). You can add a capacitor as well to filter out any transients on the line.

[image]

Comment: When I pull it to ground with a resistor, the chip will turn on at power up and reset instead of powering down the device after interval. I am not running a microcontroller. The chip alone do that if tied to ground. I will try a capacitor, maybe I get transients when powereing up with done pulled low

Comment: Bit of thinkering later, found a bad solder joint on the en/one_shot pin. Got the done pin to sort of work. Now I have a 80-100k short circuit between done and ground throwing all my timing off, but at least it does what it's supposed to do if I calculate the parralele resistor value taking that short into account.

Comment: 80 to 100k Ohm ist Not a short

Comment: Just had to wait longer for the 80-100k to return to open circuit. it's just something the chip does after reading the value. Rabbit hole. Cleaned everything, Worked nicely ever since. Huge saving on batteries . Thanks guys, I kept missing that bad joint until I asked here lol.